# Can anyone tell me if they see an error in the following PHP code?

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

For some reason, the while loop below never fires.
All of this is inside a class.

```
$code = $this->get_postal_state_no('Western Cape');

private function get_postal_state_no($psn)
    {
        $sql = "
                SELECT 
                    no
                FROM  
                    ct_state 
                WHERE 
                    name LIKE('".$psn."');";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn1, $sql);
        // This statement is not false, so the error handling does not happen, this is expected.
        if($stmt === FALSE) 
        {
            if(($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != NULL) 
            {
                foreach($errors as $error) 
                {
                    $sqlstate       = $error['SQLSTATE'];
                    $code           = $error['code'];
                    $sqlmessage     = $error['message'];
                }
            }
            $msg = 'Error in $stmt in get_postal_state_no() method.';
            $this->do_error_log($error_msg, $sqlstate, $code, $sqlmessage, $msg, __LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __CLASS__, __METHOD__);
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        }
        //This loop is never entered.  This is not expected.

        while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) 
        {
            echo "I am here now";
            break;  
            if(!empty($obj->no) && $obj->no != '') 
            {
                echo "Hello, I exist";
                break;
                // This break never happens
                return $obj->no;
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Hello, I don't exist";
                break;
                // This break never happens
                $code = $this->sp_aa_iud_ct_state($psn);
                return $code;
            }
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea why? I am using the php_sqlserv driver.  The SQL server profiler shopws the query for the first part executing.

Thanks

J

Comment: Did you do any debugging already? Does the query actually return >0 rows? Are you getting any errors/notices (that might be suppressed)? Is the `while()` actually reached?

Comment: @kingkero Yes, I have.  I am getting no errors in my custom logging.  The if statement in the while loop either returns a code if there is one, or if not, calls another method that creates a new code and returns it to this method.  If I break right before the while, it breaks.  If I break during any of the if conditions, it simply continues, since it seems as if the while is reached, but never executed.

Comment: From the PHP Documentation on `sqlsrv_fetch_object`: *Returns an object on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs or if the specified class does not exist.* So consider using an appropriate condition in your while clause since otherwise it might end in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation page for [sqlsrv_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php) it says this about the return value:

> Returns an object on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs or if the specified class does not exist.

I suspect the function is either returning `NULL` or `FALSE`, though the reasons are a little unclear.  Try adding this above the `while` loop and see what the output is:

```
$obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)
var_dump($obj);
die;
while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) 
{ // ...
```

Another helpful debugging trick is to dump out the query and then copy/paste it into your DBMS system and run the query you are executing in code directly against your database to see if any results are actually being returned:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        no
    FROM  
        ct_state 
    WHERE 
        name LIKE('".$psn."');";
var_dump($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was getting back an unhandled NULL.

Comment: :) np, glad I could help